# How to increase the search performance in huge list in python?

Tags: python, loops, search

I have a huge list with skills and i am searching target skills in this list in loop as below:-

```
skillset = []
for skill in skills:
                if skill in tokens:
                    skillset.append(skill)
```

Here **skills** has all the skills and i am searching each skill in **tokens**(which i want to search) and if found then append the value in another list skillset.

It is working fine but taking too much time.

So could any one help on that how to improve the search performance?

Suppose skills = [java, sql, python, php] and 
tokens =['i','know','java','and','php','is','good,'language']

now i need to fetch only java and php from tokens and for that i am searching each token in skills data to get the php and java.

Skills list has 15k records and tokens has many tokens with skills.

Comment: For the container you are searching, consider changing from `list` to `set` for much faster search performance.

Comment: @CoryKramer could you please help on this?

Comment: How many skills and how many tokens?

Comment: @TedBrownlow, suppose skills =[ java, sql, spring, ptyhon] now i have to search java in list so now i need to search each word in list in loop. skills has 15k skills and tokens has text with skills in token form. so i need to extract the skills to match the skill in skills list.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a set intersection for this

```
>>> skillset = set(tokens).intersection(skills)
>>> skillset     
{'php', 'java'}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be as follows:

```
tokenset = set(tokens)
skillset = [s for s in skills if s in tokenset]
```

If the order of `skillset` does not need to conform with the order in `skills`, you can simply do:

```
skillset = set(akills) & set(tokens)
```

This will return a `set` named `skillset`, which you may want to convert to `list` if you need to do anything other than sequential access and membership tests.

Either solution will run in time proportional to the size of the larger set of values. The second solution is likely to be faster, as it has a fixed set of Python instructions to perform.